# association issue with php-activerecord & codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I'm using php-activerecord + sparks + codeigniter 2.0 and stuck trying to figure out the association between three tables.

I three tables :

### Tables

> contacts | primary_key = contact_id
>
> collections | (join table) primary_key = id, other keys would be contact_id & route_id
>
> routes | primary_key = id

I think it should be **A Route** *has many* **collections** and *belongs to* a **contact**

I can get the route has many collections to work but can not get the correct contact details to appear per collection, only get returned data on one contact.

hope that makes sense.

Thanks for any help

David.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a fourth table. If a route has many collections and only belongs to one contact, you might be looking for

```
contacts | contact_id
collections | collection_id
routes_to_collections | route_id (foreign key), collection_id (foreign key)
routes| route_id, contact_id (foreign key)
```